# How to resume network upgrade of Ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, upgrade, ubuntu-server, dpkg

I'm upgrading from Ubuntu server 10.04 to 10.10 via ssh / byobu.  It's gotten to samba configuration window (conflict between smb.conf), however I lost internet connection.

When I log back in and go back into byobu, I can't find the setup windows anymore.  However there are still locks on the system and running `ps aux | grep root` returns (relevant lines):

```
root     10753  0.0  0.4  11940  7008 pts/7    S+   11:38   0:00 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.postinst configure 2:3.4.7~dfsg-1ubuntu3.6
root     10779  0.0  0.0   1848   556 pts/7    S+   11:38   0:00 /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.postinst configure 2:3.4.7~dfsg-1ubuntu3.6
root     10795  0.0  0.0   4940  1228 pts/7    S+   11:38   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/bin/ucf --three-way --debconf-ok /var/run/samba/upgrades/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf
root     10836  0.0  0.0   5568  1184 pts/7    S+   11:38   0:00 whiptail --backtitle Package configuration --title Samba Server --output-fd 11 --nocancel --default-item keep the local version currently installed --menu A new version of configuration file /etc/samba/smb.conf is available, but the version installed currently has been ?locally modified.??What do you want to do about modified configuration file smb.conf? 18 120 7 -- install the package maintainer's version  keep the local version currently installed  show the differences between the versions  show a side-by-side difference between the versions  show a 3-way difference between available versions  do a 3-way merge between available versions (experimental)  start a new shell to examine the situation 
root     12461  0.0  0.0   2452   844 ?        S<s  11:18   0:00 udevd --daemon
root     16127  0.0  0.2   7360  4520 pts/7    Ss+  11:32   0:01 /usr/bin/dpkg --force-overwrite --status-fd 27 --configure libc-dev-bin linux-libc-dev libc6-dev libc6-dbg libdrm2 libdrm-nouveau1 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-radeon1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libfreetype6 gettext-base grub-common dmsetup libck-connector0 libdbus-glib-1-2 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libxau6 libxdmcp6 libxcb1 libx11-data libx11-6 dbus consolekit hdparm libaio1 mime-support readline-common libreadline6 libsqlite3-0 python2.6 libpython2.6 libasound2 libgcrypt11 libtasn1-3 libgnutls26 libkeyutils1 libkrb5support0 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libgssapi-krb5-2 libidn11 libsasl2-2 libldap-2.4-2 libcurl3-gnutls libpci3 libwrap0 libx11-xcb1 libxext6 libxi6 libxtst6 libpulse0 libsdl1.2debian-alsa libsdl1.2debian iproute python seabios qemu-common qemu-kvm net-tools ifupdown xkb-data pciutils bzip2 libsasl2-modules libpng12-0 libplymouth2 mountall plymouth libxml2 libperl5.10 perl perl-modules libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-client3 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsdriver1 libjpeg62 libtiff4 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libpaper1 liblcms1 libpoppler7 libslp1 poppler-utils libgs8 gsfonts ghostscript cups-common cups-client openssl ssl-cert ttf-freefont cups-ppdc cups update-inetd cups-bsd foomatic-filters wget libcurl3 curl foomatic-db-engine python-central apt-utils python-apt apt-transport-https libboost-iostreams1.42.0 libxapian15 libept1 libcwidget3 aptitude cron libntfs-3g79 ntfs-3g diff fvwm-icons gawk libatk1.0-0 libpixman-1-0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxrender1 libcairo2 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgp11-0 libgtk2.0-common libnewt0.52 libpopt0 whiptail dialog defoma libpango1.0-common libdatrie1 libthai-data libthai0 libxft2 libpango1.0-0 libxfixes3 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxinerama1 shared-mime-info libgtk2.0-0 libgcr0 dbus-x11 gnome-keyring libgnome-keyring0 python-newt libgail18 libgtk2.0-bin librsvg2-2 locales language-pack-en-base language-pack-en linux-image-2.6.35-28-generic linux-image-2.6.35-28-generic-pae mktemp libxkbfile1 libgomp1 gcc-4.4-base libmpfr4 cpp-4.4 binutils gcc-4.4 libstdc++6-4.4-dev g++-4.4 cpp x11-apps libfontenc1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx x11-utils x11-xkb-utils dhcp3-common dhcp3-client gpgv gnupg iputils-ping libcap2 liblockfile1 lockfile-progs logrotate ntpdate ubuntu-keyring sudo ureadahead vim-gui-common vim-common vim-runtime libart-2.0-2 libbonobo2-common libbonobo2-0 gconf2-common libgconf2-4 libogg0 libtdb1 libvorbis0a libvorbisfile3 libcanberra0 libavahi-glib1 psmisc gconf2 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnome2-common libgnome2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomecanvas2-0 libbonoboui2-common libbonoboui2-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomeui-0 libgpm2 libruby1.8 vim-gnome vim vim-tiny ubuntu-minimal apparmor liburi-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tree-perl libwww-perl librpc-xml-perl libapparmor1 libapparmor-perl apparmor-utils at bash-completion libgeoip1 libisc60 libdns66 libisccc60 libisccfg60 libbind9-60 liblwres60 bind9-host dnsutils bsdmainutils busybox-static command-not-found-data python-gdbm command-not-found dosfstools ftp geoip-database libffi5 libgirepository1.0-1 gir1.0-glib-2.0 groff-base iptables iputils-tracepath libcap-ng0 irqbalance iso-codes libelf1 libgc1c2 libtimedate-perl libmailtools-perl libparted0debian1 libpcap0.8 ltrace make man-db manpages memtest86+ nano openssh-client openssh-server parted plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text ppp python-support python-gobject python-gobject-cairo strace tcpdump time ttf-dejavu-core language-selector-common rsync usbutils ubuntu-standard ufw update-manager-core uuid-runtime w3m acpid python-problem-report python-simplejson python-httplib2 python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python-lazr.uri python-wadllib python-zope.interface python-lazr.restfulclient python-launchpadlib python-apport apport python-xapian python-debian apt-xapian-index libavahi-core7 avahi-daemon avahi-utils postfix bsd-mailx gcc g++ libdpkg-perl dpkg-dev build-essential screen byobu libchm1 libchm-bin chm2pdf libwbclient0 samba-common winbind samba-common-bin samba smbclient cifs-utils smbfs libpam-smbpass gcc-4.3-base cpp-4.3 gcc-4.3 l
root     18458  0.0  0.9  45948 14272 pts/0    S+   10:13   0:02 /usr/bin/python /tmp/tmpVQXrVj/maverick --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText
root     29698  0.2  0.9  45160 14880 pts/0    S+   09:59   1:12 /usr/bin/python /tmp/tmpVQXrVj/maverick --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText
```

If I run `do-release-upgrade` again it tries to upgrade to 11.04.  I can't run `dpkg --configure -a` or `aptitude full-upgrade` because of locks.  What's my best course of action:

- kill processes and reconfigure and aptitude upgrade
- reboot and reconfigure and aptitude upgrade
- restart machine and upgrade to 11.04

Please keep in mind I'm about 11,000 km from my server right now.

Comment: You should be able to kill `dpkg` and restart using `dpkg --configure -a`. Even in case it doesn't work, it should be fixable as long as you have SSH access (don't reboot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured out what my problem is.  I have the server auto run byobu upon ssh login.  For some reason or another, it's creating a new byobu session rather than resuming the old one.  When I exit byobu but am still on the server, `byobu -R` can't find any existing sessions.  However `screen -DR` does find the pre-existing byobu/screen session and I'm able to resume the upgrade.